# PayPal checkout not displaying item's name?

Tags: paypal

Consider these two links to PayPal:

- [Donation payment link](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&item_name=whatever&no_shipping=1&tax=0&amount=1&business=church@fbny.org&currency_code=USD&item_number=4145414)
- [Buy Now payment link](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=whatever&no_shipping=1&tax=0&amount=1&business=church@fbny.org&currency_code=USD&item_number=4145414)

When users click the first, they will see `item_name` and `item_number`.  For the Buy Now one, however, when users click this one they won't see the `item_name` and `item_number`.

How can I show the item's name and number on a Buy Now link?

Comment: This seems like a better question for Paypal user support directly. Read tag description. _For user-level support, contact PayPal directly using their site_

Comment: Paypal community is horrible. When you try to post a question it always gives you an error saying "Include descriptive keywords in the subject line that will make your topic unique." I can't even make a post there except for this one: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/General-Discussions/Include-descriptive-keywords-in-the-subject-line-that-will-make/m-p/2985570

Comment: Indeed, @shenkwen. Paypal community is just the worst ever. I use the Paypal community on Reddit now

Answer (score 2):

> How can I show the item's name and number on a Buy Now link?

It's there -- click the cart icon+price in the upper right to see item detail.

All normal PayPal checkouts work this way.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What about item number? It's less important but I'd rather it displays

Comment: Depending on which version of the PayPal Checkout you get, there may be a "More" link to see additional item detail. Or there may not.